# Instrumenting ios application

Tags: ios, instrumentation

I have instrumented an app from xcode and installed into iPhone,

Can I copy the iPad file and install it on another device for testing, rather than installing through xcode?

Comment: Do you want to install ipa file to the device? I know a website that could online installation ipa file without jailbreak. http://www.chuaiguo.com/ipa

Answer (score 0):

Try [Crashlytics/Fabric](http://docs.fabric.io/ios/beta/index.html), it has both crash report analytics tool and beta distribution tool integrated. It's a very easy way to invite beta testers to test your app.

You can also use [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) provided by Apple, for testing apps uploaded to iTunesConnect before releasing it.